# Can I change the SSH deny/allow order?

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I am trying some ssh tricks and stuck on a server.

Is there a way to make ssh `hosts.deny` read before `hosts.allow`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access control based on `hosts.deny` and `hosts.allow` is provided by the TCP wrappers library (`libwrap0`). This is what its `README` file says:

> The wrapper programs have no interaction with the client user (or with
>   the client process).  Nor do the wrappers interact with the server
>   application. This has two major advantages: 1) the wrappers are
>   application-independent, so that the same program can protect many
>   kinds of network services; 2) no interaction also means that the
>   wrappers are invisible from outside (at least for authorized users).

Also look at the [hosts_access](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/hosts_access.5.html) manpage:

> ```
> ACCESS CONTROL FILES
>        The access control software consults two files. The search stops at the
>        first match:
>
>        ·      Access  will  be  granted when a (daemon,client) pair matches an
>               entry in the /etc/hosts.allow file.
>
>        ·      Otherwise, access will be denied  when  a  (daemon,client)  pair
>               matches an entry in the /etc/hosts.deny file.
>
>        ·      Otherwise, access will be granted.
> ```

So, unless you compile a custom version of `libwrap0`, there's no way to change its current behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, if a same IP is on both /etc/hosts.deny and /etc/hosts.allow then the access will be granted. To force the deny you should ensure that the script that adds to /etc/hosts.deny does remove the IP from /etc/hosts.allow.